# Android - How to stop an animated imageView immediatly?

Tags: android

Is there any way to stop the imageView animation immediatly before the end of the given duration ?

My Code that animates the imageView is :

### ImageView image;

### image.animate().translationX(0).setDuration(3000);

looking for a way how to stop the animation before these 3 seconds (Conditionally)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is  image.clearAnimation();